upgrading to websocket without access to the underlying http server
i'm writing an express middleware that know how to respond to many endpoints, most of them pure http, but some of them are special that require bi-directional communication (websockets).
normally, when you have access to the http server you can achive this with the following:
import http from 'http';
const server = http.createServer(app);
app.listen = function serverListen(...args) {
    return server.listen(...args);
};
const wss = new WebSocketServer({ server: server });
wss.on('connection', (ws) => {
    ws.on('message', (message) => {
        console.log('Received:', message);
        ws.send('Message received: ' + message);
    });
});
server.on('upgrade', function upgrade(request, socket, head) {
    wss.handleUpgrade(request, socket, head, function done(ws) {
        wss.emit('connection', ws, request);
    });
});

the above implementation works as expected. the upgrade event provide us request, socket, and head parameters which are crucial in order to call correctly to wss.handleUpgrade.
the things is, that i don't have access to the underlying http server, and i couldn't find any implementation on the internet that extract request, socket, head directly from express request and response objects passed to the middlewares. (before anyone suggest, express-ws also relies on http server).
currently, i was able to correctly extract request and socket parameter from express, but i am missing the head parameter.
wss.handleUpgrade(req, req.socket, ???, (websocket) => {
    wss.emit('connection', websocket, req);
});

as you can see: we get request from express.request, socket from express.request.socket but head is missing.
with the help of AI and MDN docs i was able to get one step closer in re-constructing the head parameter.
here the code:
if (path === '/transaction/.websocket') {
    // this is a transaction request
    console.log('Transaction request');

    // Check if the request is a WebSocket upgrade request
    if (!req.headers.upgrade || req.headers.upgrade.toLowerCase() !== 'websocket') {
        return res.status(400).send('Invalid WebSocket upgrade request');
    }

    // Get the value of the 'Sec-WebSocket-Key' header
    const secWebSocketKey = req.headers['sec-websocket-key'];
    if (!secWebSocketKey) {
        return res.status(400).send('Missing Sec-WebSocket-Key header');
    }
    // Construct the `head` buffer according to the WebSocket protocol
    // see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Sec-WebSocket-Accept
    const secWebSocketAccept = crypto
        .createHash('sha1')
        .update(secWebSocketKey + '258EAFA5-E914-47DA-95CA-C5AB0DC85B11=')
        .digest('base64');

    const head = Buffer.from(
        `HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols\r\nUpgrade: websocket\r\nConnection: Upgrade\r\nSec-WebSocket-Accept: ${secWebSocketAccept}\r\n\r\n`,
    );
    
    // Handle the WebSocket upgrade
    wss.handleUpgrade(req, req.socket, head, (websocket) => {
        wss.emit('connection', websocket, req);
    });
    
}

but not i get on the server response Uncaught RangeError: Invalid WebSocket frame: RSV1 must be clear.
this is where i was able to get so far. any help would be appreciated.
relevant:

NodeJS, WebSockets, upgrade head


What do you mean with "underlying web server"? If this is about a reverse proxy in front of the application then this one needs to be aware of the upgrade to websocket in order to properly implement the reverse proxy functionality.

let's assume that upgrade: websocket is enough for the middleware to understand that this is upgrade event. my main issue here is how to recustrcut head parameter as the question explains
